# How can I get completion and tooltips based on company mode in Emacs Ipython Notebook?

Tags: completion, company-mode, ipython, ein

I am using Emacs 24.5.1 and John Miller's [fork](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) of the Emacs IPython Notebook (EIN) client. The documentation indicates support for auto-completion based on auto-complete mode. As I am a company-mode user, I would like to use this mode for auto-completion, but I'm stuck on how to do this.

Within regular Python files I use the Python mode of `python.el` (sometimes with or without Elpy) and it works perfectly. When typing a dot, I get nice tooltips (and additional documentation strings) shown. In addition, I can get documentation on every Python function easily with `C-c C-d`.

Is there any way to get this working in EIN? Any help is appreciated!